# delete python mysql issues

Tags: python, mysql

In order to delete the table named cars I created in python-mysql , I do

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'priceapi', 'data', 'carpricedb');
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM cars");
con.commit()
con.close()
```

But I get an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "delete.py", line 4, in <module>
cur.execute("DELETE FROM cars");
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in     defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

My Table only has 78 rows. I also tried truncating the table. The result is the same. 
I tried doing it directly in mysql , but then it doesnt execute the command and I had to kill it using Control+C. I searched a lot for the last 1 hour, but could not find the solution .

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete is very very very very slow SQL operation and i guess that the table is huge so it takes a lot of time to finish. It's best to drop and recreate a table if you want it clear (truncate is a 2nd best option).

It is also possible that some query is locking your table, you can clear that lock off by stopping and starting mysql again (or by finding which query is doing that and kill it).

Comment: I tried truncating the table. It did not work.  By the way, my table only has 78 rows

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? And the fastest approach is to just drop the table and then recreate it so give that a try.

Comment: mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE cars;
    ^CCtrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 158" to server ...

Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted

I waited for 10 minutes before pressing control c

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh: that sounds like an issue on higher level than just table and data, maybe a corrupted file/issues with harddrive? Can you select from the table? Can you drop it?

Comment: I can select from the table, but can't drop . I use linux

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh: Indeed this seems like a case of filesystem/hdd corruption/failure. Best course of action would be to create a new database, import all your tables/data into it and... drop the old database. Maybe that will push it through, but you certainly should check integrity of your fs.

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh actually it also may be a lock, please just try resetting the mysql server and see whether that will clear it up (shut it down completely, make sure it's not listening on port and then start it).

Comment: Now it worked. Can  you explain me why is it ? and can you please edit your answer accordingly so that i can rate ur answer

Comment: @ThothadriRajesh comments are important part of answer too, but i will edit it in a second. What happened is that you had a query that locked a table from being used (be it because of an update, or very complex select, another delete statement). You can read more on locking in manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39757/discussion-between-thothadri-rajesh-and-puciek)